# NHibernate Many-to-many with a boolean flag on the association table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am doing some work on an application that uses an existing schema that cannot be altered. Whilst writing my NHibernate mappings I encountered a strange many-to-many relationship. The relationship is defined in the standard way as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722038/many-to-many-mapping-in-nhibernate) with the addition of a boolean flag on the association table that signifies if the relationship is legal. This seems somewhat redundant but as I say, cannot be changed.

Is it possible to define this relationship in Nhibernate without resorting to using a third class to represent the association? Perhaps by applying a filter?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something I run into quite a bit with NHibernate and keep coming back to the following resources. [This article](http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2008/05/29/nhibernate-many-to-many-collections-or-mapping-is-not-one-table-one-class.aspx) explains how you can create the Many-to-Many association and [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421075/applying-the-hibernate-filter-attribute-to-a-bag-with-a-many-to-many-relationship) shows how you can create the filter on your Many-to-Many without having to map the actual association class.

Comment: No problem. It's something I have to do often enough to know the resources, but not often enough to have committed it to memory yet :)